# fesm2020/ngx-translate-multi-http-loader.mjs:2:0-41 - Error: Module not found

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

updated my ngx-translate-multi-http-loader from 8.0.2 to 9.3.1 throws module not found error.
my error looks like

```
./node_modules/ngx-translate-multi-http-loader/fesm2020/ngx-translate-multi-http-loader.mjs:2:0-41 - Error: Module not found:
```

Error: Can't resolve 'deepmerge-ts' in node_modules\ngx-translate-multi-http-loader\fesm2020'

```
changed my module .ts TranslateModule.forRoot({
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
    deps: [HttpBackend],
  },
}),and in declation export function HttpLoaderFactory(http:HttpBackend{return new MultiTranslateHttpLoader(http, []
```

my angular v-14.2.10

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please perform a proper research before asking a question. I very quickly found this GitHub issue which seems to be exactly about your problem: https://github.com/rbalet/ngx-translate-multi-http-loader/issues/25

Answer (score 0):

The loader will merge all translation files from the server using deepmerge-ts.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge-ts

=> npm i deepmerge-ts

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).